# Issue on the Gravity Form

Tags: wordpress

In the first page of form, I am using the "name" field. In the third page of form, again I am using same "name" field. I want to show validation error, If the value of "name" field in third form page is different from the value of "name" field in first page of form

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My previous answer was deleted since it didn't contain the full source code of the solution; you can find that here: https://gravitywiz.com/custom-field-confirmation/